# How to prove that rigid bodies have fixed areas during their movements?

Tags: geometric-measure-theory, rigid-transformation

a rigid body is a pair of: a set $S$ of points with at least two distinct points on space $\mathbb R^3$ and a special continuous position function for each point of $S$ $f:S \times [t_1,t_2] \to \mathbb R^3$, such that $f(x,y,z,t)$ gives the position of point $(x,y,z)$ at the moment $t$ with the property that for any two points $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ and any instants $t_1$ and $t_2$ we have that: $$||f(x_1,y_1,z_1,t_1)-f(x_2,y_2,z_2,t_1)|| = ||f(x_1,y_1,z_1,t_2) - f(x_2,y_2,z_2,t_2)||$$

with this analytic approach, can we prove that the area of $S$ does not change over $t$? The set $S$ at the instant $t$ is given by $f(S,t)$.

I think this come to proving that the shape of $S$ doesn't change, but how to formalize this?

EDIT: is my definition of $f$ problematic?

Comment: My impulse is, assuming the set $S$ is measurable to begin with, to prove the claim in the special case of a rectangular box, extend the result to finite unions of boxes, and finally use a limiting argument.

In particular for the first stage, you only have three dimensions of freedom and eight corners, so it shouldn't be hard to prove that the corners of your box are rigid with respect to each other.  From there, you can easily show each interior point is rigid as well, and then you're basically there.

Comment: @EliJohnson that is a nice approach

Comment: Are you assuming that each slice of $f$ at a given $t$ is one-to-one?

Comment: I believe you can prove that @RobArthan (that f is injective in space but not time)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to prove something more general, since the result doesn't depend on continuity of $f$ or $n=3$.

> **Lemma:** Let $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, and let $f:S \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be such that $\|p-q\| = \|f(p) - f(q)\|$ whenever $p,q\in S$. Then $f$ is a composition of reflections, rotations and translations.

In particular $m(S) = m(f(S))$ whenever $S$ is measurable. This implies your version; fix $t_1$ and $t_2$ and consider that $f(\cdot,t_1)\mapsto f(\cdot,t_2)$ is a function satisfying the conditions of the lemma.

For more detail see [Euclidean isometries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_group).  In this case the function is restricted in domain to $S$.

*Proof:*

**Case 1**: $S$ contains an affinely independent set of cardinality $n+1$.

Let $A = \{a_1,\ldots,a_{n+1}\} \subseteq S$ be an affinely independent set. We construct the composition of reflections, rotations and translations necessary to identify $A$ with $f(A)$:

1. Compose $f$ with a translation to identify $a_1$ with $f(a_1)$
2. Next, compose with a rotation about $a_1$ to identify $a_2$ with $f(a_2)$. This is possible since $\|a_1 - a_2\| = \|f(a_1) - f(a_2)\|$
3. Continue composing with rotations that fix all previously identified points, and identify the next point.  Since affine rotations fix an $n-2$-dimensional affine subspace, and distances match, and the points are affinely independent, this is possible up to the second-to-last point.
4. Once $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ have all been identified, if $a_{n+1}$ and $f(a_{n+1})$ are already identified, great.  Otherwise, consider the set $H$ of points $h$ such that $\|a_{n+1} - h\| = \|f(a_{n-1}) - h\|$ is a hyperplane which must contain $\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$. Therefore composing with a reflection across $H$ identifies $a_{n+1}$ with $f(a_{n+1})$ while leaving the rest fixed.

Let $\widehat{f}$ be the above composition of $f$ with translations, rotations and reflections. I claim $\widehat{f}$ is the identity on $S$.  Suppose not, for a contradiction.  Then there is $x\in S$ with $x\not = \widehat{f}(x)$.  Note that $\widehat{f}$ is also an isometry, since it is a composition of isometries, so $x$ and $\widehat{f}(x)$ have the same distance to each point in $A$.  Just as in step 4 above, this implies $A$ is contained in a hyperplane.  But this is impossible, since $A$ is affinely independent of cardinality $n+1$.  Therefore $\widehat{f}$ is the identity, which means $f$ is a combination of reflections, rotations and translations.

**Case 2**: $S$ contains no affinely independent set of cardinality $n+1$.

Given a maximal affinely independent set $A := \{a_1,\ldots,a_k\}$, we can identify $A$ with $f(A)$ as before (in fewer steps).  Once again let $\widehat{f}$ be the composition of $f$ with these isometries, and suppose for a contradiction there is $x\in S$ with $x\not = \widehat{f}(x)$.  As before $A$ must be contained in the hyperplane between $x$ and $\widehat{f}(x)$.  As $x$ is not in this hyperplane, $x$ is affinely independent with $A$, contradicting the maximality of $A$, and we're done.